# Positive optional lookahead

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find three matches in these lines, Last name, first name and title. The typical lines are like:

- 1SMITH/JOHNMR-AA1
- 1SMITH/JANEMRS-AA2
- 1SMITH/JOHNNY-AA3

The last one does not have the title.

A regex like the following would work fine on the first two, but would of course not handle the last one:

`^1([A-Z]+)\/([A-Z ]+)(?=MRS?)(MRS?)?-(.*)$`

A regex like the next one would handle the last line, but not the first two:

`^1([A-Z]+)\/([A-Z ]+)(?=MRS?|-)(MRS?)?-(.*)$`

In this last case the title becomes part of the first name-match, since I assume it does the look ahead from the end backwards to find either the title or the dash (and the dash is found first). How can I change the pattern so that it will find the title first instead of the dash?

Comment: Use `^1([A-Z]+)\/([A-Z ]+?)(MRS?)?-(.*)$`

Comment: Thanks. I realized this myself after 1 second after I posted. Guess you sometimes just have to write your own thoughts down.

Comment: You might make it even more versatile, say, try `^1([^\/]+)\/(.*?)(MRS?)?-(.*)$`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `(?=MRS?)(MRS?)?` is actually the same as `(MRS?)` (the group is obligatory) and the `([A-Z ]+)` pattern is greedy. You should make the former optional, `(MRS?)?` and the latter non-greedy, `([A-Z ]+?)`.

I suggest using

```
^1([^\/]+)\/(.*?)(MRS?)?-(.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/joIoWz/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `1` - a `1` char
- `([^\/]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `/`
- `\/` - a `/` char (note you may probably write it even without escaping, it depends on how you use the regex pattern)
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(MRS?)?` - Group 3 (optional): `MR` and an optional `S`
- `-` - a `-` char
- `(.*)` - Group 4: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.